# Not managing to chain selectors with $ and $$ as documented in Webdriver-IO docs

Tags: webdriver-io, spectron

I'm using Spectron's WebdriverIO which is at version 4.7.1 in node_modules. I'm trying to getText from an element but selecting it gradually is giving me trouble.

I can "Copy -> selector" in dev tools to give me a very specific path. This works if I `.element(longPath)`.

What isn't working for me is chaining with `$` and `$$` (or `element` / `elements`):

```
const name = await client
  .$($sideNav)
  .$$($storageItem)[0]
  .$('.StorageItem__header-info___browser-main-SideNav- span')
  .getText()
```

Accessing `[0]` gives me `undefined`. If I log out the resolved value of `$$($storageItem)`, I get:

```
[ { ELEMENT: '0.16994195059314898-2',
    value: { ELEMENT: '0.16994195059314898-2' },
    selector: '.StorageItem__root___browser-main-SideNav-',
    index: 0 } ]
```

Any ideas why I can't chain as shown in the [example here](http://webdriver.io/v4.7/api/utility/$.html): http://webdriver.io/v4.7/api/utility/$.html

Many thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem! Did you find a solution to this problem???

Comment: @Andreas sorry this was not an important project. I'm not sure if I worked around it or gave up as it was not important. I remember asking on the project's gitter and getting no help either. Can you see if you can select what you want some other way?

Comment: I found that chaining $ and $$ is not possible. For every call the client needs to be used... Thank you anyway...

Comment: I created objects for every elements. Then I use jQuery selectors to map them like you and also mainSelector for every page. That helps tests to find object more efficient. Spectron look for child elements under mainSelector. I am sharing example script.         this._selectorsMap.set(HistoryPageElements.HISTORY_RESULTS, `${this._mainSelector} .history-list-elements.history-item span `);

Comment: @slckayhn could you elaborate?